# Triggering copying and renaming of spreadsheet onFormSubmit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Using onFormSubmit bound to the spreadsheet to which the form is linked, I wrote a script that copies another spreadsheet and renames it. Currently the new name is set within the script. The point of the form, though, is for teachers to enter their email, last name, first name and teacher number and then have a registration form (spreadsheet) sent to them for them to fill out. Too I want the new name of the copied spreadsheet to use the teacher's last name and first name. So far, my script is not working. Based on research, though, it seems that it out to. So, here is the initial script, which works:

```
function onFormSubmit() {
  const teacher = 'GuessKevin';
  const SourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1ARnOku-h49TAZytmEGSnckAKaoMZqffQ');
  const Files = DriveApp.getFileById('1_uHtcG-qLEeETGNbhRA4WNwQYcaltXbAtxgupYQNWLY');
  const FileRename = Files.makeCopy(teacher + '-Registration-FallFestival', SourceFolder);
}
```

And here is the new script, which isn't working, not even the copying of the spreadsheet part:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const formResponses = e.getResponses();
  const teacherEmail = formResponses[1].getResponse();
  const teacherName = formResponses[2].getResponse() + formResponses[3].getResponse();
  const teacherNum = formResponses[4].getResponse();
  const SourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1ARnOku-h49TAZytmEGSnckAKaoMZqffQ');
  const Files = DriveApp.getFileById('1_uHtcG-qLEeETGNbhRA4WNwQYcaltXbAtxgupYQNWLY');
  const FileRename = Files.makeCopy(teacherName + '-Registration-FallFestival', SourceFolder);
}
```

I've also tried using the form's Id, as follows, but that hasn't worked either:

```
function onFormSubmit() {
  const form = formApp.openById('1hKoK1FNLYohXqK3hhkNkQ6z-IQgzXGRUcjm0YEmvOE4');
  const formResponses = form.getResponses();
  const teacherEmail = formResponses[1].getResponse();
  const teacherName = formResponses[2].getResponse() + formResponses[3].getResponse();
  const teacherNum = formResponses[4].getResponse();
  const SourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1ARnOku-h49TAZytmEGSnckAKaoMZqffQ');
  const Files = DriveApp.getFileById('1_uHtcG-qLEeETGNbhRA4WNwQYcaltXbAtxgupYQNWLY');
  const FileRename = Files.makeCopy(teacherName + '-Registration-FallFestival', SourceFolder);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're using `onFormSubmit` for a script that is bound to a spreadsheet that is linked to a Google Form. You need to look more closely at the [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) returned by `e` (and how to access those objects) because `getResponses()` is **NOT** a valid event object. Insert `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))` as the first row of code in `onFormSubmit(e)` to display the actual Event Objects available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script needs to use the [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) that apply to a spreadsheet-bound `onFormSubmit` triggered script.

The Event Objects can be displayed by using `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))` but in general terms they are:

- values in an array named `values` (of which the first entry is the timestamp) or
- key/value pairs in an object named `namedValues`.

In this answer, I have used the `values` array.

**Reminder**:
The function `makeTeacherSheet` must be triggered by an installable `onFormSubmit` trigger. Since the function is attached to the spreadsheet, the trigger must be created from the same Spreadsheet "Triggers" tab.

---

```
function makeTeacherSheet(e) {
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))
    var values = e.values
    var teacherEmail = values[1]
    var teacherName = values[2]+values[3]
    var teacherNum = values[4]
    Logger.log("DEBUG: email:"+teacherEmail+", Name: "+teacherName+", Number: "+teacherNum)
    var SourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1ARnOku-h49TAZytmEGSnckAKaoMZqffQ')
    var Files = DriveApp.getFileById('1_uHtcG-qLEeETGNbhRA4WNwQYcaltXbAtxgupYQNWLY')
    var FileRename = Files.makeCopy(teacherName + '-Registration-FallFestival', SourceFolder)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I assumed it had something to do with retrieving the desired data correctly. Unfortunately, your code isn't working either, but you've given me a direction to research.

Comment: `Unfortunately, your code isn't working either,` I'm sorry that I couldn't test the script because there was no sample data, BUT I would like to know more about this. 1) I neglected to mention that you must create an installable trigger for this function based on "on Form Submit". Have you done that? 2) Would you please check the "Executions Log": 2) is the script generating a "FAILED" error? If so, would you please advise details. 3) I deliberately left two `Logger` statements in the script; would you please advise details of the information returned by those statements.

Comment: I did create a trigger. My first script wouldn't have worked without it, would it? I'm referring to the one in which I created a var for the teacher name rather than get the name form the form entries.

Comment: If I run the script from the script page, I get this error:

Comment: Error 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'values')
onFormSubmit @ Code.gs:3

Comment: I would assume that's because the 'values' is defined in the script by entries on the form which, but the script is not being triggered by a form submission. When I submit the form (and nothing seems to happen) and then check the execution log it shows nothing. I'm not sure how that's supposed to work, so I'm not sure if that means the script wasn't triggered. I clicked "debug" and lists all the variables as undefined, beginning with 'e.' The two Logger files aren't generating anything, as far as I can tell, which I would guess is because 'e' is undefined...?

Comment: "Curiouser and curiouser" 1) Check that the spreadsheet is linked to the form. 2) **I renamed the function** => `makeTeacherSheet`, please do likewise. This is to avoid the risk of multiple functions of the same name. 3) The trigger is installed manually in **spreadsheet** Project Editor; Triggers tab should display the "Event"=`From spreadsheet - On form submit` and "Function"=`makeTeacherSheet`. There should be _one and only one_ trigger with an "Event"=`From spreadsheet - On form submit`. Please confirm.

Comment: **Troubleshooting**: Once you've done (and confirmed) the foregoing, submit a form. 1) Has the relevant "Form Responses" sheet been updated with the form submission answers? 2) Is the "Last Run" column in the Editor "Triggers" tab updated? 3) Open the Executions tab, is the latest "Start time" consistent with the submission time? Click the latest row on the Executions tab to show any logged information (you may need to click "REFRESH" a couple of times). Please post the logged information.

Comment: Everything was as you say, but after the changes it didn't work. So I decided to delete the script bound to the spreadsheet and the trigger, unlink and relink the form, then create a new script (naming it "TeacherRegistration") and trigger afresh. And it worked! Thank you so much for your help. Not only did you save me tons of time, but you helped me understand how things work better.

Comment: Those are all worthwhile outcomes; well done.  Perhaps I might ask you to look at [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).